# copy a file to a destination with different names

Tags: shell, command-line, cp, brace-expansion

I want to copy a text file to a directory with multiple names with curly braces:

```
cp /path/to/file/a.txt /path/to/file/{b,c,d}.txt
```

But it gives me the error: `target '/path/to/directory/d.txt' is not a directory`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in {b,c,d}; do cp /path/to/directory/a.txt /path/to/file/$i.txt; done
```

Comment: i'm really new to this. it didn't work, no error occurred, but there is no files inside the directory. should it be inside a script?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it worked, thanks  for the answer!!